# Unable to select text field with javascript

Tags: javascript

I must be missing something basic. I can't give the textfield focus with the following:

```html
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <input id="hi"></input>
 <script>
  document.getElementById('hi').focus();
  document.getElementById('hi').select();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried to check your sample it's working. It is focusing `input` automatically

Comment: Have you try to add an on load event on the window element? Or call this in IIFE? In my case your exemple work, try to do that: (function () {
    document.getElementById('hi').focus();
    document.getElementById('hi').select();
})();

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Weird. Tried same html on two different machines.

Comment: I just surrounded your code with tags to make it an executable snippet. It seems to work fine.

Comment: Very weird. Not working for me in the snippet.

Comment: Code snippet works for me in Chrome, not Safari. Anyone else on Safari?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in Script:

> document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML

Comment: What is this supposed to fix ? This is essentially a `noop` statement